# Customising the IRF plot

Tags: r, plot, customization

I am trying to customise the plot generated by:

```
plot(irf(VECMcoeff, n.ahead = 20, cumulative = FALSE, ortho = TRUE))
```

Current figure:

Not yet allowed to post figures.

Is there a way, using R's basis plotting functions, to adjust this plot? More specifically;

1. I would like to have plots stand-alone from each other.
2. Adjust x- and y-axis titles.
3. Adjust the main title.
4. Remove the '95 % Bootstrap CI, 100 runs'.

Thanks for any help!

Data:

```
dput(head(combined,25))
structure(c(3.12378036948822, 3.24514490963516, 2.54231015523096, 
3.10758964326189, 3.26905177146087, 3.39086921629928, 3.39867627597089, 
3.063339608249, 2.82158440194456, 3.00060851536641, 2.87498214357332, 
2.73447964251719, 2.51961774067125, 2.43535838893541, 2.53536474393679, 
2.11458263713232, 2.08443293370433, 1.70951997715485, 1.6939353104687, 
1.99402766681289, 2.17851574489578, 2.02035721460859, 2.19849725222166, 
2.12385225312224, 2.13870052300126, 2.53563259854902, 2.71236841778707, 
2.80602806173539, 2.44978220282482, 2.22240349195674, 2.6269002941349, 
2.55424892433652, 2.84227347851153, 3.00695212249206, 2.56409065301929, 
2.11958065079056, 1.93021828518557, 1.91149187923047, 2.12824458610721, 
1.99034383037538, 1.85993728242216, 1.78831122085649, 1.70508421574581, 
1.34148894168009, 1.26428948883955, 1.53707667916106, 1.40125321322403, 
1.56189928398736, 1.59267901471992, 1.29435444758231, 2.88357952825106, 
3.2967949657277, 2.71315870827614, 2.88194083947586, 2.55384396254808, 
2.48162552588286, 2.43461752858767, 2.60895931242784, 2.88699097436266, 
3.06774759389068, 2.92820858177705, 1.9236817467793, 1.30469143981917, 
1.63412478606386, 1.32569634585868, 1.66411340281953, 1.811114177636, 
1.32324449480086, 0.683740288067047, 0.506428412402278, 0.244160570695116, 
-0.0614637978267916, 0.11100051693192, 0.107431188637327, -0.0946163941762501, 
1.56887584570782, 2.2953989716194, 2.3913948824343, 1.60366568545365, 
2.14074303245166, 1.42821783272864, 1.14416900596202, 1.32550310805691, 
1.06775704738626, 1.1754985484452, 1.30819594680082, 1.57801107586324, 
1.57465869540119, 1.52953051921855, 1.59632502092932, 1.51164066108273, 
1.74699133577352, 1.89513403376172, 1.50403737650093, 1.69077755145674, 
1.51619819345532, 1.7908456553931, 1.63120428277988, 1.72264300428443, 
1.91016040082409, 2.93953881174612, 0.573867521584496, 1.36693966408554, 
1.33745582274447, 2.00217541671565, 1.47500074486359, 1.54892810099376, 
1.52596101747453, 1.85097710190023, 1.8027452973638, 1.71255671138078, 
1.78801314649281, 1.73039561596535, 1.7797925346833, 1.68662137367852, 
2.10887254895115, 2.47630376444312, 2.10728662380876, 1.99939507617536, 
2.1661652656972, 1.97780409080129, 2.08116163569287, 2.33934227442197, 
2.38773088163046, 2.39899888596041), .Dim = c(25L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("rstar.nl2", "rstar.ger2", "rstar.fr2", "rstar.sp2", 
    "rstar.it2")))
```

Comment: Could you post your data so that we could generate the same figure?

Comment: Can you also post what package the `irf()` function is from?

Comment: 'vars' package. How can I post some data without clogging the entire post? Because the data frame is a 5 x 150 matrix.

Comment: Your `dput` dumps a sample of the variable `combined` but your code refers to `VECMcoeff` .  Are they the same?

Comment: combined contains the data, VECMcoeff contains the estimated VECM model based on that data; so there are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat general advice:

`plot()` is a generic function that actually calls a more specific function (called a "method") depending on what you are trying to plot (see [this](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html) chapter from Hadley Wickham's *Advanced R* book for details).  In this case, you are feeding-in an object of class "varirf" to `plot()`.  You can see this by running, e.g.:

```
out <- irf(your_arguments_go_here)
class(out)
```

The generic function `plot()` is calling the method `plot.varirf()` because you are feeding in an object of type "varirf". To see which parameters of `plot.varirf()` you can control, check out that function's help page

```
?plot.varirf
```

If this doesn't provide you with sufficient control over what you want your plot to look like, then you should abandon trying to use `plot.varif()` and construct your desired plot manually, as in:

```
plot(x=my_x_vals, y=my_y_vals, main="My Title", pch=20, col="red", etc.)
```

In manually creating your plot, you may find it useful to see how `plot.varirf` plots are created so you can implement some of the same formatting. To view the source code for `plot.varirf`, use:

```
getAnywhere(plot.varirf)
```

Comment: This is not only very helpful for this question, but I have just learned something very valuable for other scenarios! Thanks! From what I can see in the help file, a lot of elements are set NULL by default, so hopefully by changing those values I can adjust the plot as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
plot(x, plot.type = "single", names = NULL, main = "IRF to a one-standard deviation shock to APP", sub = NULL, lty = NULL, lwd = NULL, col = NULL, ylim = NULL, ylab = "Eonia", xlab = "Number of periods", mar.multi = c(0, 4, 0, 4), oma.multi = c(6, 4, 6, 4), adj.mtext = NA, padj.mtext = NA, col.mtext = NA)
```

where, x is your varest object,

Good luck!